# Extracting information about Programming skills from dbpedia using Python?

Tags: python, dbpedia

Suppose I have some tokens and I want to know whether a particular token is programming skill or not so I want to cross validate it with dbpedia to know whether it is programming skill or not. How I can do this? I used some code:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    SELECT ?label
    WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Python_(programming_language)> rdfs:label ?label }   
    """)

sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
print(result["label"]["value"])
```

but from the output I am not getting info about whether Python is a programming language or not.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if entity `Python_(programming_language)` exists, it means `Python` is a programming language. With your approach, if you want to check token `X` is a programming or not, you can query whether page `X_(programming_language)` exits. But this fact is not true for all programming languages.

A better way is getting a list of all programming languages, then check wheter your token in this list or not. You can use [this query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fpl%20%3Flabel%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Fpl%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%3Fpl%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3AProgrammingLanguage%20.%0D%0AFILTER%20%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%3D%27en%27%29%0D%0A%7D%20%20&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
    SELECT ?pl ?label
    WHERE { 
        ?pl rdfs:label ?label .
        ?pl rdf:type dbo:ProgrammingLanguage .
        FILTER (LANG(?label)='en')
    }  
    """)

sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
results = results["results"]["bindings"]
programming_languages = [item["label"]["value"] for item in results]
print programming_languages
# [u'ALGOL', u'AMOS (programming language)', u'APL (programming language)', ...]
```

Comment: Actually I want to implement the concept:                                                 Suppose I have skills dictionary with some known skills.A sentence in job description identified as having at least two known skills (known skills are those present in the skills database).Sentence is converted into tokens . Each unknown token is validated to be an actual skill
by cross-referencing with DBpedia .  Now suppose that unknown token  is "Data Structure", so how I can validate this token as skill using dbpedia.

Comment: I haven't understood clearly, what do you expect if the unknown token is "Data Structure"?. It will be better if you can provide some more detail examples

Comment: I want to implement ML algorithm to automatically learn what  job skills are & extract them from both job posting and resumes. First we create skills dict with some known skills. This skill dict is updated iteratively using training set of job description. Now suppose one of the sentence in job description is ['Must have good knowledge of Data Structure']. After some cleaning operation I have tokens ['knowledge','Data Structure']. Now I want to validate this tokens from dbpedia whether they are skills or not. How I can do this so that after validation I will add Data Structure in skills dict.